# How can I modify the registration form on the website Odoo 12?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I need to add other fields to the registration form that brings the web site module by default, I imagine that I can inherit from somewhere to add it to my own module, the inheritance does not know if it should be in the python or in the xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find XML template for that registration and using xpath and doing controller inherit to pass values you can able to do that.